# Is Haskel School of Music going to ever be finished?

Tags: haskell, audio, reactive-programming

I'm writing bachelor thesis about reactive programming in Haskell. I'm using Euterpea to develop simple audio application. I almost finished *Haskell School of Music* by Paul Hudak.

But, as some of you know, Mr. Hudak passed away earlier this year and the book is now finished - chapters on frequency modulation  are only half way done. Physical Modelling chapter has a lot of empty spaces. I can't understand ideas presented there if there is no explanation :(

Is there any information whether the book is going to be finished?
I don't even know how can I obtain such information.

Is anyone except Paul Hudak involved in writing *Haskell School of Music*?

Comment: I don't think this is actually on-topic for SO. I'm not going to vote to close, but I think a better place to ask would probably be the [haskell-cafe](https://mail.haskell.org/mailman/listinfo/haskell-cafe) mailing list.

Comment: @dfeuer thanks for the tip. I msged them :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not directly about programming.